# 'xxx' cannot be resolved (String, Scanner etc.) after importing files

Tags: eclipse

I took a backup of my workspace. Meanwhile I created another workspace in my pc after formatting for temprory purposes. So now I've imported everything from my hard disk to my pc from `File -> Import`. However nothing seems to be 'resolved'. Heres an example of the code:

```
package com.sarthak.main;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Myfirstgame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Momo Land, a place full of horror and utter momoness ");
        System.out.println("Enter Your Name: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name=input.nextLine();
        MyGame game=new MyGame(name);
        game.run();

    }

}
```

Things like `System.out.println` , `input game.run` etc. can't be resolved for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your Java libraries are referenced in the properties of your project. In most cases, it is the referencing problem when importing projects.

Comment: All the projects are unchecked in referenced menu . Strangely out of all the projects imported , some projects work and some do not.

Comment: Is your JavaSE library referenced in the libraries tab? If it is a problem with multiple projects, check the same in Window>Preferences.

Comment: I'm sorry but i'm unable to rectify the problem . Doesn't seem to work. I noticed that I imported 3 projects out of which only 1 doesn't work . rest all seem to work fine .

Comment: Right click on your project and select Properties. Click on Java Build Path on left pane. Then, on right pane select Libraries. Is there any JRE library listed? If not, you will need to add it using 'Add Library' option. If there is any red cross on the listed JRE, then remove that and add the JRE again using 'Add Library' option.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project and then just copy the code inside the files..This may solve your problem.

Comment: Should I create new classes altogether in the new project and then copy all the code or just copy existing classes into the new project ?